# I import wikipedia, I get the error... AttributeError: module 'certifi' has no attribute 'where'

Tags: python, python-3.x, certifi

I type into a python 3 jupyter notebook...

```
import wikipedia as wp
```

I get a long error, the end of which reads...

```
c:\users\yishai and shira\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\certifi.py in <module>
      3 http = urllib3.PoolManager(
      4     cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
----> 5     ca_certs=certifi.where())
      6 ##The PoolManager will automatically handle
      7 ##certificate verification and will raise SSLError if verification fails:

AttributeError: module 'certifi' has no attribute 'where'
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Turns out, I had a *file* named certifi. I changed its name. Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating certify module, it should work:

```
pip install --upgrade certifi
```